# Norm of a continuous, linear operator defined on $l^\infty$

Tags: continuity, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I am struggling to find the solution to this problem.

Let $f: l^{\infty} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous linear functional, where $l^{\infty} := \{x=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R} : ||x||_{l^{\infty}} := \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_n| < \infty\}$. Assume that $f(x) \ge 0, \forall x=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n \ge 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, let $f(\overline{x}) = 2021$, where $\overline{x} = (1, 1, …, 1, …)$. Calculate the norm of $f$ in the topological dual of $l^{\infty}$.

I know that for a continuous linear functional the norm is defined as follows
$||f|| := \sup_{x \in l^{\infty}, x \ne 0} \frac{|f(x)|}{||x| |_{l^{\infty}}}$
or, equivalently, taking the supremum of the sequences with $l^{\infty}-$norm equal to 1. But I don’t know how to proceed in the reasoning in order to estimate the norm. Should I use the continuity of $f$ in $\overline{x}$?

Any suggestion/hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can rewrite the definition of the norm of $f$ as follows:
$$||f|| = \sup_{||x|| \le 1} |f(x)| = \sup_{||x|| = 1} |f(x)|$$
which is either already known to you or is relatively easy to prove.

So we know for sure that $||f|| \ge 2021$. I am claiming that indeed $||f|| = 2021$. Assume for contradiction $||f|| > 2021$, which means there is a $y \in \ell^{\infty}$ with $f(y) > 2021$ and $||y||_{\infty} = 1$.

We can write $y= (y_1, y_2, y_3, \dots)$ and know by the definition of the norm on $\ell^\infty$ that $|y_k| \le 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$. That implies $1- y_k \ge 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$. If we now take
$$z:= (1-y_1, 1-y_2, 1-y_3, \dots)$$
we have $y+z = \bar{x}$ so $f(y+z) = f(\bar{x}) = 2021$ but also $f(y+z) = f(y) + f(z) \ge f(y) > 2021$ because $z$ is non-negative in each component. This is a contradiction so there is no $y \in \ell^\infty$ with $||y||_\infty = 1$ and $f(y) >2021$.

Therefore $||f|| = 2021$.

Comment: Thanks! It seems really immediate now, but I am still learning how to solve functional analysis problems, thus I am not very skilled in this area. Your prompt help has been extremely appreciated!